# Can't add a property to a prototype in javaScript

Tags: javascript

Trying to better understand prototypes so I went to my console and entered this:

```
    function Dog(){}

    Dog.prototype.breed = breed;

    Dog.prototype.talk  = function(){

    console.log('I\'m a ' + this.breed);

    };


    dog1 = new Dog();


    dog1.breed = 'poodle';

    dog1.talk();

    //This is what I get...
    //ReferenceError: breed is not defined
```

**Update** I used `null` and it works perfectly....Funny though, using `Dog.prototype.name = name;` works!

```
    Dog.prototype.name = name;
    //Dog.prototype.breed = null;
    Dog.prototype.talk  = function(){

    console.log('my name is ' + this.name );

    };


    dog1 = new Dog();

    dog1.name = 'charly';
    //dog1.breed = 'poodle';

    dog1.talk();
```

Comment: "Using `name` works" - because `window.name` is a variable that already exists. It's not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: wow...Totally blown away. I have been reading Professional JavaScript for Web Developers and that makes total sense...So would you use 'null' when creating prototypes for all properties?

Comment: No. I would use default values that make sense, or just leave it off and define it per-instance. Typically in the constructor (`function Dog(breed) {this.breed = breed;}`)

Comment: By default values you mean what you indicated below `Dog.prototype.breed = "mutt";`
The prototype convention seems appealing because won't creating properties in the constructor cause the instances to not share the properties and methods? Thus creating duplicates.

Comment: Well, yeah, but is `breed` a common property to all dogs? Of course not, it's a property of the individual. Therefore it should not be on the `prototype`. `Dog.prototype.numberOfLegs = 4` might be appropriate, because an individual dog *could* have `3`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dog.prototype.breed = breed;
```

You haven't defined `breed`. If you want to provide some kind of default breed, try:

```
Dog.prototype.breed = "mutt";
```